# MAC OS X Yosemite: Safari Settings

Tags: browser, safari, osx-yosemite

I want my homepage (from opening the browser) to be one thing, and then any new tabs defaulting to another page.

I don't like the "Favorites" page. I tried a tutorial on Wikihow and it didn't work.

Is there a file I need to change around to get what I want? I'm a college student on the go in a research class, and I'm tired of opening the pages when I need it! I'd rather it be there ready for me.

Peace! :3

Answer (score 1):

You can get chrome to open on a specific set of pages!
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95314?hl=en

Chrome is a great browser, you should check it out!

Comment: I used Chrome in the past, but it was not reliable on my OS (Yosemite). It was constantly wigging out and crashing. Firefox was weird in the past, but I guess I could use that.

I'm just disappointed Apple didn't think of Safari holding different pages desired by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I was suggested by jimmyfund to use Chrome, but I've had no success with it on the OS X. I guess Safari does not support it regardless, so I'll just use Firefox for now. It's slower, but I hope it speeds up in time.

Safari has been the fastest browser to remain functional on my OS X. Firefox's only issue was it being slow.